# Can't find not run gddrescue

Tags: 18.04

I have installed ddrescue on my 32 bit Ubuntu MATE 18.04 desktop but I can't figure out how to launch and run it.  Help! I can't even find it.

Comment: Not enough effort was made to research the issue by seeking out manual first.

Answer (score 2):

The `ddrescue` is terminal only application, so it runs from terminal.
You can consult with its help by `ddrescue --help`, `info ddrescue`, `man ddrescue` or by viewing its HTML documentation in `/usr/share/doc/gddrescue/html/index.html` to know how to use it.

If you want to get GUI for it - use packages [from PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ehamishmb/+archive/ubuntu/myppa):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hamishmb/myppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ddrescue-gui
```

then launch it from menu.

Comment: +1; Also `info ddrescue` contains very useful information, including a tutorial with examples.

Comment: Thanks, added mention of info.

Comment: sudodus: Thank you very much for the information regarding ddrescue.  I will give it a try at my first opportunity.  Your kind help is very much appreciated.  It is much better than the gigantic leap to the assumption that I didn't attempt to seek out the manual before asking for help.  Not all of us Linux OS users are programmers or computer geeks.  UM instructions to run-of-the-mill computer users like me are in jargon that looks like Greek, so we need help.  I don't have to write any commands to download/use a program/utility in Microsoft Windows OS.

Comment: NObert:  Thanks so much for your guidance with regard to installing a GUI version of ddrescue.  Your instruction worked like a charm.  Now I shall have to learn how to use it - should be no problem with the tutorials you suggested.  Regards.  Albert....